# Sharepoint Sites

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Is it possible to make a site "Home" in MOSS2007?

For example, when i enter my Sharepoint portal, i see two tabs on top:

Home | Just a Site

I want to delete the site under Home and set "Just a site" as default site (or Home?).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you referring to the tab section for the Top Link Bar, as illustrated in this [sample image](https://i.imgur.com/ofBFX.png)? If so, then in the Site Actions menu, go to Site Settings. Under the Look and Feel category, pick Top Link Bar. In your situation, you will probably see "Home" and "Just a Site" as the links.

Choose to edit the Home link, and delete it. Then, edit the Just a Site link, and change its name to Home. Note that the colouration for the top link tab will probably change, but this will let you direct people to "Just a Site" using a tab that says "Home".